# rust is running two tests, while I am just asking for one

Tags: testing, rust

I am trying various stuff on a project I have access to.
The command for running the tests looks something like that
`RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo +stable test --profile release --features=x86_64-unix,experimental -p name_of_root_folder filename::test_function`

I have several files running tests, and all of them have the same name for the `test_function` function. When I run the command, usually, only one test is run, discriminated by the filename.

Strangely it doesn't work for all the files, and when I try to run `filename_1` then both `filename_1` and `filename_2` tests are run, but not the others.

I don't understand why.
I can't say I'm a noob at rust, I am just generally extremely slow, and not good at programming.

How could I run only one test at a time without having to exclude them from the mod.rs by commenting them?

It seems that if I change the name of the test, it doesn't change anything, the second test still runs. I don't understand why only those two files act like that. I will try to rename the second file, maybe it is too similar to the first one but I see no universe in which that hypotesis would make sense. (yes, I can see universes)

Comment: Can you add a [mre] (creating one should be part of your debugging process anyways), if I specify the module name, then only tests from that module are run.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the fact that [a test is run if the name provided is only a part of the actual tests name](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-02-running-tests.html#running-a-subset-of-tests-by-name) i.e. `cargo test filename` will run tests that are named `filename`, `filename_1`, `filename_whatever` etc. `cargo test filename_1` however shouldn't run a test `filename` or `filename_2`.

Comment: Try with `... test_function -- --exact`.

Comment: Which test are you talking about? Unit or implementation? There is also a --test argument. The pattern matching doesn't know filenames. These are namespace paths, package, bin and lib names.

Comment: @cafce25 a minimal reproducible example will be hard to provide unless I create a bunch of folders and import, but I might try later. Running just cargo run is not enough to run the test because there are plenty of options required for the code to run. I thought about it, but although it's true the two files starts the same, they are not the same and I write a different whole name.

Comment: @cafce25 Sorry I meant "cargo test" and not "cargo run".

Comment: @trojanfoe no it's still running two tests

Comment: @Markus I don't really understand the difference between unit tests and integration tests, there is more than one method, for sure, but what is tested is a single function in a single file. The files are in a folder called test